# Ajax undefenided post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i dont know whats appen whit my code some can help?

my code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function sendmessage() {
    var namesd = $("#namesd").val();
    var dataString = {"name":namesd};
    alert(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "submitmessage.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
                $('#alert_sucess').html(html);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form>
    <input type='text' id='namesd' name='name' />
   <input type='submit' value='submit' onclick="return sendmessage()"  />
</form>
<div id='alert_sucess'></div>
```

my submitmessage.php

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
echo "name ".$_POST['name'];
} else {
echo "no post ";
}
```

on submit show alert whit values but return dont have post

Comment: Where is `alert_sucess ` defined ?

Comment: i forget post, is after form i go update

Comment: You have to give the input a name attribute: `name="name"`

Comment: yes i put now and dont work same... sorry for my old quest xD

Comment: you should add `dataType : 'json'` on your ajax request.

Comment: @Conan hi, i put now and dont return nothing i go. data: dataString,
     cache: false,
     dataType : 'json',

Comment: @x3G try this `$.ajax({
        type:"post",dataType : 'json',
        url: "submitmessage.php",
        data: dataString
        }).done(function(html){
                $('#alert_sucess').html(html);
            });`

Comment: @Conan dont post nothing dont say nothing

Comment: @x3G ok wait a moment..

Comment: Try to use this in your php `$req = file_get_contents('php://input');
 $reqParams = json_decode($req,TRUE);` and then make your condition like this `if(isset($reqParams['name'])) `

Comment: again dont say nothing :s

Comment: No error nothing ?!!

Comment: nothing.. i can try add error for see error say

Comment: on code bellow, on error say this: textStatus: open:35:25
parsererror open:36:25
errorThrown: open:37:25
SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data"